# How to set ethernet Class of Service via UDP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, ethernet

In addition to the DSCP fields in the IP header, I want to set the [Class of Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_of_Service) fields in the ethernet frame header of my UDP packets to make sure that the network hardware treats my packets with the right priorities.

Is that possible at all when using a UDP socket (created with type SOCK_DGRAM), or is this functionality available only via raw ethernet sockets (created with type SOCK_RAW)?

Comment: This is OS specific, so what's your platform ?

Comment: @nos My platform is `Linux 3.4.84-rt105 #4 SMP PREEMPT RT`

Comment: @nos But I would be interested to know for Windows as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some operating systems allow you access the related IP field Type of Service by using `setsockopt()` with the `IP_TOS` or `SO_PRIORITY` option, but some require root to do so.

I'm not aware of any means of accessing ethernet frame headers from the `SOCK_DGRAM` level.  I would not expect such to work in general, since the IP level operates independently of the link level.  In other words, a UDP/IP socket has no way to know whether any given datagram will end up on an ethernet, loopback, firewire, USB, or some other link type.

A better place to look might be the interface settings.  For example, Solaris lets you set CoS using `ifconfig`.  I'm not sure if Linux has an equivalent.  To avoid having all traffic share the same CoS, you could crate an interface alias with the adjusted CoS and then bind your socket to that.

But something to consider first is whether your network hardware actually pays attention to those fields.

Comment: Ethernet CoS is only available on VLANs. Thus one needs to configure a vlan. On linux, you can map the socket priority to the ethernet CoS with the `vconfig set_egress_map` command. The default egress map is to map all socket priorities to a value of 0 in the vlan header. The socket priority can be set with both SO_PRIORITY and IP_TOS, and can have 8 different values - though the static mapping the kernel performs from IP_TOS to the socket priority isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: Is the VLAN restriction only for Linux, or in general?  `SO_PRIORITY` is supposed to map directly to ToS for IP networks, and years ago I verified this with packet traces.  I never considered how it would map in the other direction.  I'm not aware of any network equipment which actually uses ToS.  MPLS seems to be the preferred way to handle traffic prioritization beyond the LAN.

Comment: No, it's general. Ethernet without vlan does not have CoS. It's a field in the VLAN "header", it's not present in ethernet frames without vlan. TOS is obsolete for quite a few years now, superseeded by [DSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services_code_point) (which reuses many of the bits in TOS). The DSCP is still set with the IP_TOS option though its value is bit 2-7 of what you set with IP_TOS. Enterprise networking gear supports DSCP, and most can also be configured to map DSCP to the ethernet CoS on vlans, much like one does with `vconfig set_egress_map`.

Comment: @SethNoble Many thanks for the ideas so far, this already helps. You are probably right about accessing the ethernet frames directly, but I would expect some mechanism (like SO_PRIORITY) that allows to set the priority of the underlying transport -- whatever that may be.

Comment: @nos Would you mind adding your comments as an answer, I think they are valuable.